# Mapping Column values to integers

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which I load in R which looks like this:

```
id    binary_value    multivalued_attribute1    multivalued_attribute2
0     0               value11                   value22
1     0               value15                   value24
2     0               value11                   value22
3     1               value14                   value22
```

The binary values are a simple `yes or no` question whereas the `value1x` and `value2x` are string values with a finite number of values each.

How can I switch the multivalued columns in to numeric data so I can plot a heatmap? Because trying to plot while those are strings takes too much time.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that `value11` maps to `11` and `value22` maps to `22`?

Comment: what about `as.numeric(factor(...))`

Comment: How do you want to do the mapping? The heatmap isn't going to be that interesting if you just randomly replace with numbers? What exactly is the desired output? What are the rows and columns and colors supposed to represent? What is the call to `heatmap()` that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
dat$multivalued_attribute1 <- as.numeric(factor(dat$multivalued_attribute1))
dat$multivalued_attribute2 <- as.numeric(factor(dat$multivalued_attribute2))
```

where `dat` is your dataframe ...